# cannot upgrade to wsl2

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am going to upgrade my wsl 1 to wsl 2 to use docker because when I run `docker version` I don't find anything for server: docker engine.

[image]

I have already activated "Windows subsystem for Linux" and "virtual machine platform" the in the "Turn windows features on or off"

[image]

However, hardware virtualization is disabled.

[image]

Then, I followed all the steps in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual) and still cannot have WSL 2 on my laptop. Could you please tell me what I should do?

Here, you can find some information on my system:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @8Simon8 - What is the output of `wsl --install`? Verify that hardware virtualization is enabled.

Comment: @8Simon8 - **We cannot help you without the output.**  Does the command execute successfully?  If it does and you have hardware virtualization enabled then you should simply reboot your system. Take a screenshot(s) of the output, but redirecting the output of that command to a file, would be the best solution.

Comment: "I don't find the virtualization in the "task manager > performance" window." - [Edit] your question, do not reply to this comment, and indicate which processor you have.  The fact you DO NOT have the an indication it if hardware virtualization enabled or disabled, indicates to me your processor DOES NOT support hardware virtualization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140621/discussion-between-ramhound-and-8simon8).

Comment: Please also note that while WSL 2 is required to run Docker on WSL, it will not provide great tooling around Docker. Do consider using Docker Desktop (with WSL 2 Engine) instead.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I the virtualization is disabled.

You need to enabled Hardware Virtualization, in order to use `Virtual Machine Platform`, which is required to convert your WSL1 instance to WSL2.  **Until you enable Hardware Virtualization on your machine you will be unable to convert your WSL1 instance.**

> Before installing WSL 2, you must enable the Virtual Machine Platform optional feature. Your machine will require [virtualization capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#error-0x80370102-the-virtual-machine-could-not-be-started-because-a-required-feature-is-not-installed) to use this feature.

Source: [Enable Virtual Machine feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-3---enable-virtual-machine-feature)

After you enable Hardware Virtualization, run `wsl --install` in an elevated PowerShell prompt, in order to enable everything required for WSL2 and then restart your machine.

> You can now install everything you need to run WSL with a single command. Open PowerShell or Windows Command Prompt in administrator mode by right-clicking and selecting "Run as administrator", enter the wsl --install command, then restart your machine.

Source: [Install WSL command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install#install-wsl-command)

It is worth pointing out you can only run `wsl --install` if WSL is not installed, so the simplest solution to not having everything you required installed, is to uninstall Windows Subsystem for Linux then run the command.

> The above command only works if WSL is not installed at all, if you run wsl --install and see the WSL help text, please try running wsl --list --online to see a list of available distros and run wsl --install -d  to install a distro. To uninstall WSL, see [Uninstall legacy version of WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#uninstall-legacy-version-of-wsl) or [unregister or uninstall a Linux distribution.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands#unregister-or-uninstall-a-linux-distribution)

Comment: I enabled the virtual machine feature using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOuTxfzCvMY&t=10s). and then followed all the steps in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual), but it is still `wsl 1`.